# Error Python numpy con Windows

Tags: python, windows, numpy, python-import

Siendo novato en programación cometí el graso y blasfemo error de desinstalar mi versión 3.8.5 e instalar la versión 3.9.0. junto con las librerías que utilizaba.
Como mis programas no corrían desinstalé 3.9.0 e instalé 3.8.2 y volví a instalar librerías como OpenCV, bs4, etc.. sin embargo al correr el siguiente código:

```
import cv2
```

Visual Studio Code y el IDLE de Python me mandan el error:

```
"numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"
```

desinstalé numpy y lo volví a instalar, y en google llevo dos días buscando que pueda ser sin embargo solo me he encontrado con que hay que reinstalar numpy pero no me está funcionando.

incluso intenté hacer un  `import numpy` previo a `import cv2` pero me muestra el error:

```
The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.
```

Si alguien puede recomendar alguna documentación para encontrar el error y solución o sabe que está pasando se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: pero cual windows estaba usando el? windows 10? windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te está sucediendo es que al desinstalar e instalar estás instalando **la última versión de `Numpy` que tiene errores con Windows.** En teoría este error ser resolverá para Enero de 2021, puede verse en el [foro de desarrolladores de windows](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html) y también en [Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16744)

La **solución** es instalar una versión anterior a `1.19.4`, puedes elegir la versión ejecutando:

```
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto esto solucionó mi problema muchas gracias!!!!