# Python Moviepy error

Tags: python

tengo un error con moviepy, pero es un error GIGANTE, me dice sobre varias librerias como numpy, imageio, .core, etc

Cualquier cosa que haga con moviepy no funciona, ya sa usando gifs, convirtiendo mp4 a mp3, etc

```
from moviepy.editor import *
#o usando esto me pasa lo mismo
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip("xd.mp4")

clip.write_gif("mygif.gif")
```

Este es el error, se supone que tiene que ver con varias librerias pero al instalar moviepy te instala todas las de el error automaticamente(use pip list para comprobar y tengo todo)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mi usuario :v/OneDrive/Bibliotecas/Python/Archivos py/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import *
  File "C:\Users\mi usuario :v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 24, in <module>
    import imageio
  File "C:\Users\mi usuario :v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\imageio\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .core import FormatManager, RETURN_BYTES
  File "C:\Users\mi usuario :v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .util import Image, Array, Dict, asarray, image_as_uint, urlopen
  File "C:\Users\mi usuario :v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\util.py", line 19, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\mi usuario :v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\mi usuario :v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\mi usuario :v\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: https://tinyurl.com/y3dm3h86
```

Comment: Hola Alan, esta es la respuesta a tu error! [Error Python numpy con Windows](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413201/error-python-numpy-con-windows)

Comment: neta muchas gracias :D me pasaba lo mismo con opencv pero ya esta arreglado

Comment: Un detalle curioso: Eso no es un error "gigante", de hecho, es de los más pequeños que he visto. Básicamente te dice lo que ocurre en la última linea...